# C#: Writing a CookieContainer to Disk and Loading Back In For Use

Tags: c#, file-io, cookies, httpwebrequest, cookiecontainer

I have a **`CookieContainer`** extracted from a HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse session named *CookieJar*. I want my application to store cookies between runs, so cookies collected in the `CookieContainer` on one run of the program will be used the next run, too.

I think the way to do this would be to somehow write the contents of a CookieContainer to disk. My question is:

- How can you **write a CookieContainer to the disk**? Are there built-in functions for this, or, if not, what are the approaches people have taken? Are there any classes available for simplifying this?
- Once you've written a CookieContainer to the disk, **how do you load it back in for use**?

**UPDATE:** The first answer has suggested **serialization** of the `CookieContainer`. However, I am not very familiar with how to serialize and deserialize such complex objects. Could you provide some **sample code**? The suggestion was to utilise `SOAPFormatter`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I Haven't tried it but it has the attribute Serializable and so can be [de]serialized with .net binary serialization, e.g. SoapFormatter.

Here is the code snippet you asked for.

```
var formatter = new SoapFormatter();
string file = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "cookies.dat"); 

using (Stream s = File.Create (file))
    formatter.Serialize(s, cookies);                            
...
CookieContainer retrievedCookies = null;
using (Stream s = File.OpenRead (file))
    retrievedCookies = (CookieContainer) formatter.Deserialize(s);
```

Looking at msdn it seems SoapFormatter is now deprecated in .net 3.5 and it recommends you use Binaryformatter. In the past I have found SoapFormatter useful as the file is readable which helps with diagnosis when deserialization fails! These formatters are sensitive to version changes even in the assembly version (so if you deserialize with one version of the framework upgrade the framework, then it might not deserialize, not sure), but there are ways around this with the Binder property if this becomes a problem. I believe they are primarily designed for short term persistance / remoting, but they might be good enough for you here.

The new DataContractSerializer does not seem to work with it so that is out.

An alternative would be to write a CookieContainerData class to [de]serialize with XmlSerializer and manually convert between this and CookieContainer.

Comment: I don't know too much about serialization, so could you provide some sample code?

Answer (score 39):

This problem was bugging me for ages, nothing I could find worked. I worked it out, so putting that information out into the world.

Answer using BinaryFormatter:

```
    public static void WriteCookiesToDisk(string file, CookieContainer cookieJar)
    {
        using(Stream stream = File.Create(file))
        {
            try {
                Console.Out.Write("Writing cookies to disk... ");
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(stream, cookieJar);
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Done.");
            } catch(Exception e) { 
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Problem writing cookies to disk: " + e.GetType()); 
            }
        }
    }   

    public static CookieContainer ReadCookiesFromDisk(string file)
    {

        try {
            using(Stream stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
            {
                Console.Out.Write("Reading cookies from disk... ");
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Done.");
                return (CookieContainer)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        } catch(Exception e) { 
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Problem reading cookies from disk: " + e.GetType()); 
            return new CookieContainer(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is anyway that I can store in SQL instead of a file?

Comment: BinaryFormatter  is obsolete now https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/binaryformatter-serialization-obsolete
This solution is no longer valid

Answer (score 9):

All of the previous answers are outdated since serializing using `IFormatter` classes was deprecated https://aka.ms/binaryformatter

So the correct method now is serializing it using something else that supports `IEnumerable<T>`.

Here's an example using `System.Text.Json`

### Serialize

```
await using var fs = File.OpenWrite("cookies.json");
// Beware: GetAllCookies is available starting with .NET 6
JsonSerializer.Serialize(fs, cookieContainer.GetAllCookies());
```

### Deserialize

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
await using var fs = File.OpenRead("cookies.json");
var cookieCollection = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CookieCollection>(fs);
cookieContainer.Add(cookieCollection);
```

Answer (score 6):

It is interesting to have **cookies in text format**. Besides being able to be used to write to disk, it can be used for other purposes.

WORKS FOR ME!

Use the `LoadCookiesFromFile` and `SaveCookiesToFile` functions to load and write the cookies to the disk respectively.

Or use the `GetCookies` and `SetCookies` functions to do the same thing, but to manipulate it as a string.

```
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

void LoadCookiesFromFile(string path)
{
    SetCookies(cookieContainer, File.ReadAllText(path));
}

void SaveCookiesToFile(string path)
{
    File.WriteAllText(path, GetCookies(cookieContainer));
}

string GetCookies(CookieContainer cookieContainer)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(stream, cookieContainer);
        var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Position = 0;
        stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }
}

void SetCookies(CookieContainer cookieContainer, string cookieText)
{
    try
    {
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cookieText);
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            cookieContainer = (CookieContainer)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //Ignore if the string is not valid.
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call that "cookies in text format". It's "binary data as base64". I think cookies themselves are text, so it would be possible to store cookies as human readable text if you wrote your own text-based serializer - it could be JSON, or simply indented text sections.