# SerializeObject and DeserializeObject

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7.1

I use this following code but it gives error

**Service1.svc.cs**

```
 public static byte[] SerializeObject<T>(T obj)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(ms))
            {
                DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                dcs.WriteObject(writer, obj); writer.Flush();
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

client code Windows phone

```
public static T DeserializeObject<T>(byte[] xml) 
    { 
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(xml)) 
        {
            using (XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(memoryStream, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max)) 
            {
                DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T)); 
                return (T)dcs.ReadObject(reader); 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

I call this **DeserializeObject** from below code

```
   void svc_Get_Conn(object send, GetConnCompletedEventArgs e)
    {  
        CookieContainer con =DeserializeObject<CookieContainer>(e.Result);
    }
```

This gives following **error**

```
Message = "Type 'System.Net.PathList' with data contract name 'PathList:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Net' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using...
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

CookieContainer can't be serializable. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777203/c-writing-a-cookiecontainer-to-disk-and-loading-back-in-for-use) workaround

cheers